# Apache: What is the best way to handle thousands of permanent redirects?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, 301-redirect

We've a list of 3000 301 redirects. We need assistance on

1. What would the best place to put these? It seems putting these 3000 lines inside vhost in httpd.conf would be a mess.
2. What are recommended ways to handle thousands of urls?
3. How much is it going to affect page loading speed and apache server load ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `Include` directive in `httpd.conf` to be able to maintain redirects in another file. But it would not be very efficient, as every request would need to be checked against a lot of regular expressions. Also a server restart would be required after every change in the file.

A better way for so many redirects would be to use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) directive of type `dbm` to declare a map from URI's to redirects. This way it will be efficient, as dbm lookups are very fast, and after a change in the map you would not need to restart a server, as `httpd` checks for map file modification time.

A rewrite rules would look like this (tested on my Fedora 16 computer):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap redirects dbm=db:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db
RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${redirects:$1} [redirect=permanent,last]
```

And dbm map would be created from text map `/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.txt` looking like this:

```
/foo http://serverfault.com/
/bar/lorem/ipsum/ http://stackoverflow.com/
```

using a command

```
httxt2dbm -f db -i /etc/httpd/conf/redirects.txt -o /etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but getting errors:

my one line redirects.txt file content (space separated values)
http://www.mydomain.com/experiment  http://www.mydomain.com/new_page

It gave me parse error on line 'RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} != ""' . 
Syntax error on line 314 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters


I commented that out and then apache started but visiting http://www.mydomain.com/experiment (or any other url from mydomain) gave me error "request is being redirected in a way it could not be completed".

Comment: Apache is not re-starting with above snippet. Could you please help? I'm not able to see any error related to this in any of the log files.

Comment: I said it was untested - I expected that it would need some tweaking. I thought it would be enough, sorry. Httpd did not start as there can not be a space between `!=` and `""` - I've corrected my example to a working and tested version now.

Comment: One more comment: you'd need to use a different approach if your redirects need to depend on query strings (everything after `?` in URL), but [it is also possible](http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html). As it is now it would just add query string to redirect, for example `http://yourserver.com/foo?q=bar` would redirect to `http://serverfault.com/?q=bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. `RewriteMap redirects dbm=db:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db` gave error `RewriteMap dbm type db is invalid` . But when I used `RewriteMap redirects txt:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.txt` it worked. I still want to go with hashed way like you explained instead of plain text. But I could not find much about the dbm error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `httxt2dbm` command with no arguments will show you available dbm formats. In my system it was SBDM and DB. Make sure that `-f` option passed for `httxt2dbm` while generating a map (for example `-f db`) is the same as `RewriteMap` map type (for example `dbm=db:`).

Comment: In the end sdbm option worked beautifully.

Comment: Wow it works well, perfect ! (just used it with Apache Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu))

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a script that generates a new VHOST with just the links from the list.